# The collected amount repeating in every row if in case some rows are still unpaid

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

When amount was collected for the particular fees type, the invoice row is repeating below the every fees type row, the invoice row need to show only below the paid fees type. Please refer image below.

Controller:

```php
public function issueAdvance($company_id){
  if($this->session->userdata("is_active") == 1){
    $seedIssue =$this->seed_issue_model->selectFarmer($company_id);
    $singlefarmer =$this->seed_issue_model->selectIssueDates($company_id);
    $crops = $this->seed_issue_model->get_crop_data(); //Crop
    $pc_code = $this->seed_issue_model->get_pc_data(); //Production-Code
    $advance_amount =$this->advance_model->getLoanData($company_id);
    $paid_installments = $this->advance_model->paidInstallments($company_id);
    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == "GET") {
        $data = array(
           "page_content" => "advance/view_advance_issue",
           "singleFarmer" =>$singlefarmer,
           "issueSeed"  =>$seedIssue,
           "crop_result" =>$crops,
           "pc_result" =>$pc_code,
           "farmer_loan" =>$advance_amount,
           "paid_installments" =>$paid_installments
        );
        $this->load->view("layout/main_layout",$data);
     } else{
             
     }
   }
}
```

Model:

```php
public function getLoanData($company_id){
  $query = $this->db->select('a1.farmer_id,a1.advance_id,b1.balance_id,a1.amount,a1.check_no,a1.given_date,a1.due_date,b1.reason,b1.season,b1.mode,b1.balance')
   ->from('tbl_advance as a1')
   ->join('tbl_balance as b1', 'b1.advance_id=a1.advance_id')
   ->where("a1.farmer_id", $company_id)
   ->order_by('a1.given_date', 'desc')
   ->get();
   $result = $query->result();
   return $result;
}
public function paidInstallments($company_id){
  $query = $this->db->select('a1.farmer_id,a1.advance_id,b1.balance_id,p1.amount_paid,p1.amount_discount,p1.paying_date,p1.payment_id,p1.payment_mode,p1.description,p1.balance_id')
   ->from('tbl_pay_amount as p1')
   ->join('tbl_balance as b1', 'p1.balance_id=b1.balance_id')
   ->join('tbl_advance as a1', 'b1.advance_id=a1.advance_id','p1.advance_id=a1.advance_id') 
   ->where("a1.farmer_id", $company_id)
   ->get();
   $result = $query->result(); 
   return $result;
}
```

View of this part code:

```php
<tbody>
    <?php

        $total_amount = 0;
        $total_discount_amount = 0;
        $total_balance_amount = 0;
        $total_paid_amount = 0;
        
        foreach ($farmer_loan as $key => $balance) {
            $discount_amount = 0;
            $paid_amount = 0;
            $total_amount = $total_amount + $balance->amount;
        }

        foreach ($farmer_loan as $index => $value) {
            if (!empty($value->payment_id)) {

                $paid_amount = $paid_amount + $value->amount_paid;
                $discount_amount = $discount_amount + $value->amount_discount;
            }
        ?>

        <?php
            $balance_amount = $value->amount - ($discount_amount + $paid_amount);
            $total_balance_amount = $total_balance_amount + $balance_amount;
            $total_discount_amount = $total_discount_amount + $discount_amount;
            $total_paid_amount = $total_paid_amount + $paid_amount;

            if ($balance_amount > 0) {
        ?>
            <tr class="danger font12">
        <?php
            } else {
        ?>
            <tr class="dark-gray">
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="fee_checkbox"
                data-advance_id="<?php echo $value->advance_id ?>"
                data-balance_id="<?php echo $value->balance_id ?>"
                data-farmer_id="<?php echo $value->farmer_id ?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->check_no ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->amount ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->reason ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->season ?></td>
        <td> </td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="left" class="text text-left width85">
            <?php
                if ($balance_amount == 0) { ?>
                    <span class="label label-success">Paid</span>
                <?php
                    } else if (((int)$value->balance)==(int)($value->amount)) { ?>
                <span class="label label-danger">Unpaid</span>
                <?php
                    } else { ?>
                <span class="label label-warning">Partial</span>
                <?php
                    } ?>
          </td>

        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->due_date ?></td>
        <td class="text text-center">
            <?php echo (number_format($discount_amount, 2, '.', '')); ?></td>
        <td class="text text-center">
            <?php echo (number_format($paid_amount, 2, '.', '')); ?></td>
        <td class="text text-right">
            <?php $display_none = "ss-none";
                if ($balance_amount > 0) {
                    $display_none = "";
                    echo (number_format($balance_amount, 2, '.', ''));
                }
                ?>
        </td>   
        <td><?php echo $value->given_date ?></td>

        <td>
            <div class="btn-group pull-right amount">
                <?php if ($paid_amount != $value->amount ){ ?>
                    <button type="button"
                    data-advance_id="<?php echo $value->advance_id; ?>"
                    data-balance_id="<?php echo $value->balance_id; ?>"
                    data-farmer_id="<?php echo $value->farmer_id; ?>"
                    data.title="Collect Amount"
                    class="btn btn-xs btn-default myCollectFeeBtn <?php echo $display_none; ?>"
                      data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#myFeesModal">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                <?php if($paid_amount == 0.00){ ?>
                    <button type="button"
                    data-advance_id="<?php echo $value->advance_id; ?>"
                    data-balance_id="<?php echo $value->balance_id; ?>"
                    data-farmer_id="<?php echo $value->farmer_id; ?>"
                    class="btn btn-xs btn-default myCollectFeeBtn <?php echo $display_none; ?>"
                    title="Edit Row" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myFeeModal">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default"
                    data-advance_id="<?php echo $value->advance_id; ?>"
                    data-balance_id="<?php echo $value->balance_id; ?>"
                    data-farmer_id="<?php echo $value->farmer_id; ?>"
                    title="Delete Row">
                    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i> </button>
                <?php 
                }
                ?>
                <?php
                    } else { ?>
                        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default"
                    data-advance_id="<?php echo $value->advance_id; ?>"
                    data-balance_id="<?php echo $value->balance_id; ?>"
                    data-farmer_id="<?php echo $value->farmer_id; ?>"
                    title="Print Row">
                    <i class="fa fa-print"></i> </button>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
          
    <?php
                
        foreach ($paid_installments as $index => $value) {

          ?>
              <tr class="white-td" id="">
                  <td align="left"></td>
                  <td align="left"></td>
                  <td align="left"></td>
                  <td align="left"></td>
                  <td align="left"></td>
                  <td class="text text-left">
                      <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" class="detail_popover" > <?php echo $value->payment_id; ?></a>
                      <div class="fee_detail_popover" style="display: none">
                          <?php
                          if ($value->description == "") {
                              ?>
                              <p class="text text-danger">No Description</p>
                              <?php
                          } else {
                              ?>
                              <p class="text text-info"><?php echo $value->description; ?></p>
                              <?php
                          }
                          ?>
                      </div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text text-left"><?php echo $value->paying_date; ?>
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td class="text text-left"><?php echo $value->payment_mode; ?></td>
                  <td></td>

                  <td class="text text-right"><?php echo (number_format($value->amount_discount, 2, '.', '')); ?></td>
                  
                  <td class="text text-right"><?php echo (number_format($value->amount_paid, 2, '.', '')); ?></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td class="text text-right">
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">

                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default printInv"
                  data-advance_id="<?php echo $value->advance_id; ?>"
                  data-balance_id="<?php echo $value->balance_id; ?>"
                  data-farmer_id="<?php echo $value->farmer_id; ?>"
                  title="Print Invoice">
                  <i class="fa fa-print"></i> </button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            <?php
          
          }
    ?>

    <?php

    }
        ?>
    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <tr class="box box-solid total-bg">
        <td align="left"></td>
        <td align="left" class="text text-left">Grand Total</td>
        <td class="text text-center">
            <?php
            echo ('<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>' . number_format($total_amount, 2, '.', ''));
            ?>       
        </td>

    <td align="left"></td>
    <td align="left"></td>
    <td align="left"></td>
    <td class="text text-left"></td>
    <td class="text text-left"></td>
    <td class="text text-left"></td>
    <td class="text text-left"></td>
    <td class="text text-right">
    <?php
          echo ('<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>' . number_format($total_discount_amount, 2, '.', ''));
      ?>    
    </td>
    <td class="text text-right">
    <?php
      echo ('<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>' . number_format($total_paid_amount, 2, '.', ''));
      ?>
    </td>
    <td class="text text-right">
    <?php
      echo ('<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>' . number_format($total_balance_amount, 2, '.', ''));
      ?>
      </td>
      <td class="text text-right"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I tried in many ways but i am not able to solve it, i m beginner to the full-stack web development please help me to overcome from this issue, now stack overflow is only my hope,need a output like if i paid some amount for the 1st row,the invoice amount row need to be display below that row only. Thanks in advance.

[image: Here is example image with screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using same variable name `$value` inside `foreach ($paid_installments as $index => $value)` loop which can collide with outer variable. So change that to some different name like `$pvalue`. And also add one check inside the loop like

```
foreach ($paid_installments as $index => $pvalue) {
        if($value->advance_id != $pvalue->advance_id )
            continue;
        ?>
        <tr class="white-td" id="">
            <td align="left"></td>
            <td align="left"></td>
            <td align="left"></td>
            <td align="left"></td>
            <td align="left"></td>
            <td class="text text-left">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" class="detail_popover" > <?php echo $pvalue->payment_id; ?></a>
        //...
        //..
```

Comment: please look into this question, i thought you can help me,  
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63314219/add-multiple-fee-paid-amounts-to-the-particular-fee-type-row