# Calculate the total paid from a foreach generated table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, conditional-statements

I was trying to add paid amount and discount sum to the fee type row but it is repeating for every fee type row if in case it is still unpaid.

Code:

```
<table id="tableFixedHeader" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="header">
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 10px"><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /></th>
                <th align="left">Check No</th>
                <th align="left">Amount </th>
                <th align="left" class="text text-left">Season</th>
                <th align="left" class="text text-left">Reason</th>
                <th class="text text-right">PID</th>
                <th class="text text-right">Date</th>
                <th align="left" class="text text-left">Status</th>
                <th class="text text-left">Mode</th>
                <th align="left" class="text text-left">Due Date</th>
                <th align="left" class="text text-left">Discount</th>
                <th align="left">Paid </th>
                <th align="left">Balance</th>
                <th class="text text-left">Issue Date</th>
                <th class="text text-right">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
                $total_amount = 0;
                $total_discount_amount = 0;
                $total_balance_amount = 0;
                $total_paid_amount = 0;
                
                foreach ($farmer_loan as $key => $balance) {
                    $discount_amount = 0;
                    $paid_amount = 0;
                    $total_amount = $total_amount + $balance->amount;
                }           
                 foreach ($farmer_loan as $index => $value) {    
                    $balance_amount = $value->balance;
                    $total_balance_amount = $total_balance_amount + $balance_amount;
                    $total_discount_amount = $total_discount_amount + $discount_amount;
                    $total_paid_amount = $total_paid_amount + $paid_amount;

                    foreach ($paid_installments as $index => $pvalue) {                        
                        if(($pvalue->advance_id != $value->advance_id))
                            continue;
                        $discount_amount = $discount_amount + $pvalue->amount_discount;
                        $paid_amount = $paid_amount + $pvalue->amount_paid;
                    }
           ?>
        <?php if ($balance_amount > 0) { ?>
            <tr class="danger font12">
        <?php } else { ?>
            <tr class="dark-gray">
        <?php }
         ?>
            <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="fee_checkbox"></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->check_no ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->amount ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->reason ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->season ?></td>
            <td> </td>
            <td></td>
            <td align="left" class="text text-left width85">
                <?php
                    if ($balance_amount == 0) { ?>
                        <span class="label label-success">Paid</span>
                    <?php
                        } else if (((int)$value->balance)==(int)($value->amount)) { ?>
                    <span class="label label-danger">Unpaid</span>
                    <?php
                        } else { ?>
                    <span class="label label-warning">Partial</span>
                    <?php
                        } ?>
             </td>

            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->due_date ?></td>
            

              <td class="text text-center">
                <?php echo (number_format($discount_amount, 2, '.', '')); ?></td>
            <td class="text text-center">
                <?php echo (number_format($paid_amount, 2, '.', '')); ?></td>                      
            <td class="text text-right">
                <?php $display_none = "ss-none";
                    if ($balance_amount > 0) {
                        $display_none = "";
                        echo (number_format($balance_amount, 2, '.', ''));
                }
                ?>
            </td>   
            <td><?php echo $value->given_date ?></td>
            <td>
              <div class="btn-group pull-right amount">
                    <button type="button">Add</button> 
              </div>
             </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                foreach ($paid_installments as $index => $pvalue) {

                    if($value->advance_id != $pvalue->advance_id )
                        continue;
                    ?>

                <tr class="white-td" id="">
                    <td align="left"></td>
                    <td align="left"></td>
                    <td align="left"></td>
                    <td align="left"></td>
                    <td align="left"></td>
                    <td class="text text-left">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" class="detail_popover" > <?php echo $pvalue->payment_id; ?></a>
                        <div class="fee_detail_popover" style="display: none">
                            <?php
                            if ($pvalue->description == "") { ?>
                                <p class="text text-danger">No Description</p>
                            <?php
                            } else { ?>
                                <p class="text text-info"><?php echo $pvalue->description; ?></p>
                            <?php
                            } ?>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text text-left"><?php echo $pvalue->paying_date; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="text text-left"><?php echo $pvalue->payment_mode; ?></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="text text-right"><?php echo (number_format($pvalue->amount_discount, 2, '.', '')); ?></td> <td class="text text-right"><?php echo (number_format($pvalue->amount_paid, 2, '.', '')); ?></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="text text-right">
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" title="Print Invoice"></button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>     
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
     <!-- FOOTER -->
    <tr class="box box-solid total-bg">
        <td align="left"></td>
        <td align="left" class="text text-left">Grand Total</td>
        <td class="text text-center">
            <?php
            echo ('<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>' . number_format($total_amount, 2, '.', ''));
            ?>       
        </td>

    <td align="left"></td>
    <td align="left"></td>
    <td align="left"></td>
    <td class="text text-left"></td>
    <td class="text text-left"></td>
    <td class="text text-left"></td>
    <td class="text text-left"></td>
    <td class="text text-right">
    <?php
          echo ('<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>' . number_format($total_discount_amount, 2, '.', ''));
     ?></td>
     <td class="text text-right">
    <?php
     echo ('<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>' . number_format($total_paid_amount, 2, '.', ''));
     ?> </td>
    <td class="text text-right">
    <?php
     echo ('<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>' . number_format($total_balance_amount, 2, '.', ''));
     ?> </td>
     <td class="text text-right"></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePVxl.png)

Controller:

```
public function issueAdvance($company_id){
        if($this->session->userdata("is_active") == 1){

          $seedIssue =$this->seed_issue_model->selectFarmer($company_id);
          $singlefarmer =$this->seed_issue_model->selectIssueDates($company_id);
          $crops = $this->seed_issue_model->get_crop_data(); //Crop
          $pc_code = $this->seed_issue_model->get_pc_data(); //Production-Code
          $advance_amount =$this->advance_model->getLoanData($company_id);
          $paid_installments = $this->advance_model->paidInstallments($company_id);
         // echo '<pre>'; print_r($paid_installments); echo ("</pre>"); exit();
          if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == "GET") {
                $data = array(
                  "page_content" => "advance/view_advance_issue",
                  "singleFarmer" =>$singlefarmer,
                  "issueSeed"  =>$seedIssue,
                  "crop_result" =>$crops,
                  "pc_result" =>$pc_code,
                  "farmer_loan" =>$advance_amount,
                   "paid_installments" =>$paid_installments
                );
                $this->load->view("layout/main_layout",$data);
            }
            else{
            }
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
public function getLoanData($company_id){
      $query = 
       $this->db->select(
        'a1.farmer_id,b1.advance_id,b1.balance_id,a1.amount,a1.check_no,a1.given_date,a1.due_date,b1.reason,b1.season,b1.mode,b1.balance')
        ->from('tbl_advance as a1')
        ->join('tbl_balance as b1', 'b1.advance_id=a1.advance_id')
        ->where("a1.farmer_id", $company_id)
        ->order_by('a1.given_date', 'desc')
        ->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        
        return $result;
    }
    
    
    public function paidInstallments($company_id){
        $query = 
            $this->db->select('a1.farmer_id,b1.advance_id,b1.balance_id,a1.amount,a1.check_no,a1.given_date,a1.due_date,b1.reason,b1.season,b1.mode,b1.balance,p1.amount_paid,p1.amount_discount,p1.paying_date,p1.payment_id,p1.payment_mode,p1.description,p1.balance_id')
            ->from('tbl_pay_amount as p1')
            ->join('tbl_balance as b1', 'p1.balance_id=b1.balance_id')
            ->join('tbl_advance as a1', 'b1.advance_id=a1.advance_id') 
            ->where("a1.farmer_id", $company_id)
            ->get();
            $result = $query->result();
            return $result;
    }
```

i m tried in many ways by adding conditions but i m not able to get a perfect answer,please help me out to resolve this bug, in the image first row is still unpaid but paid amount is not equal to zero, i need this row need to be zero if it in case unpaid.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand your question but if you want the Amount to be 0 on the unpaid rows. You can use something like this:

I added this:

```
$amount_shown = $value->amount;
if (((int)$value->balance)==(int)($value->amount)) {
    $amount_shown = 0;
}
```

And added this to your table:

```
<td><?php echo $amount_shown ?></td>
```

Full script:

```
<table id="tableFixedHeader" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead class="header">
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 10px"><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /></th>
            <th align="left">Check No</th>
            <th align="left">Amount <span>(<i class="fa fa-inr"
                        aria-hidden="true"></i>)</span></th>
            <th align="left" class="text text-left">Season</th>
            <th align="left" class="text text-left">Reason</th>
            <th class="text text-right">PID</th>
            <th class="text text-right">Date</th>
            <th align="left" class="text text-left">Status</th>
            <th class="text text-left">Mode</th>
            <th align="left" class="text text-left">Due Date</th>
            <th align="left" class="text text-left">Discount <span> (<i class="fa fa-inr"
                        aria-hidden="true"></i>)</span></th>
            <th align="left">Paid <span> (<i class="fa fa-inr"
                        aria-hidden="true"></i>)</span></th>
            <th align="left">Balance <span> (<i class="fa fa-inr"
                        aria-hidden="true"></i>)</span></th>
            <th class="text text-left">Issue Date</th>
            <th class="text text-right">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $total_amount = 0;
                $total_discount_amount = 0;
                $total_balance_amount = 0;
                $total_paid_amount = 0;

                // Why do you loop for a total here?
                foreach ($farmer_loan as $key => $balance) {
                    $discount_amount = 0;
                    $paid_amount = 0;
                    $total_amount = $total_amount + $balance->amount;
            }

                $total_amount = 0;
                foreach ($paid_installments as $index => $pvalue) {
                    
                    if(!empty(($pvalue->payment_id)))
                            $discount_amount = $discount_amount + $pvalue->amount_discount;
                            $paid_amount = $paid_amount + $pvalue->amount_paid;
                      }
                    foreach ($farmer_loan as $index => $value) {    
                            $balance_amount = $value->balance;
                            $total_balance_amount = $total_balance_amount + $balance_amount;
                            $total_discount_amount = $total_discount_amount + $discount_amount;
                            $total_paid_amount = $total_paid_amount + $paid_amount;

                            
                            if (((int)$value->balance)==(int)($value->amount)) {
                                $amount_shown = 0;
                            } else {
                                $amount_shown = $value->amount;
                                $total_amount += $amount_shown;
                            }
           ?>

            <?php
                    if ($balance_amount > 0) {
            ?>
                    <tr class="danger font12">
                <?php
                    } else {
                ?>
                    <tr class="dark-gray">
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="fee_checkbox"
                        data-advance_id="<?php echo $value->advance_id ?>"
                        data-balance_id="<?php echo $value->balance_id ?>"
                        data-farmer_id="<?php echo $value->farmer_id ?>"></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->check_no ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $amount_shown ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->reason ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->season ?></td>
                <td> </td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="left" class="text text-left width85">
                    <?php
                        if ($balance_amount == 0) { ?>
                            <span class="label label-success">Paid</span>
                        <?php
                            } else if (((int)$value->balance)==(int)($value->amount)) { ?>
                        <span class="label label-danger">Unpaid</span>
                        <?php
                            } else { ?>
                        <span class="label label-warning">Partial</span>
                        <?php
                            } ?>
                 </td>

                <td></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->due_date ?></td>
                
                  <td class="text text-center">
                    <?php echo (number_format($discount_amount, 2, '.', '')); ?></td>
                <td class="text text-center">
                    <?php echo (number_format($paid_amount, 2, '.', '')); ?></td>
                  
                <td class="text text-right">
                    <?php $display_none = "ss-none";
                        if ($balance_amount > 0) {
                            $display_none = "";
                            echo (number_format($balance_amount, 2, '.', ''));
                        }
                        ?>
                </td>   
                <td><?php echo $value->given_date ?></td>

                <td>
                  <div class="btn-group pull-right amount">
                    <?php if ($paid_amount != $value->balance ){ ?>
                        <button type="button"
                        data-advance_id="<?php echo $value->advance_id; ?>"
                        data-balance_id="<?php echo $value->balance_id; ?>"
                        data-farmer_id="<?php echo $value->farmer_id; ?>"
                        data.title="Collect Amount"
                        class="btn btn-xs btn-default myCollectFeeBtn <?php echo $display_none; ?>"
                         data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#myFeesModal">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    <?php if($paid_amount == 0.00){ ?>
                        <button type="button"
                        data-advance_id="<?php echo $value->advance_id; ?>"
                        data-balance_id="<?php echo $value->balance_id; ?>"
                        data-farmer_id="<?php echo $value->farmer_id; ?>"
                        class="btn btn-xs btn-default edit_advance_amount <?php echo $display_none; ?>"
                        title="Edit Row">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default btn-delete-advance"
                        data-advance_id="<?php echo $value->advance_id; ?>"
                        data-balance_id="<?php echo $value->balance_id; ?>"
                        data-farmer_id="<?php echo $value->farmer_id; ?>"
                        title="Delete Row">
                        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i> </button>
                    <?php 
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        } else { ?>
                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default"
                        data-advance_id="<?php echo $value->advance_id; ?>"
                        data-balance_id="<?php echo $value->balance_id; ?>"
                        data-farmer_id="<?php echo $value->farmer_id; ?>"
                        title="Print Row">
                        <i class="fa fa-print"></i> </button>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                  </div>
                 </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    foreach ($paid_installments as $index => $pvalue) {

                        if($value->advance_id != $pvalue->advance_id )
                            continue;
                        ?>

                    <tr class="white-td" id="">
                        <td align="left"></td>
                        <td align="left"></td>
                        <td align="left"></td>
                        <td align="left"></td>
                        <td align="left"></td>
                        <td class="text text-left">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" class="detail_popover" > <?php echo $pvalue->payment_id; ?></a>
                            <div class="fee_detail_popover" style="display: none">
                                <?php
                                if ($pvalue->description == "") {
                                    ?>
                                    <p class="text text-danger">No Description</p>
                                    <?php
                                } else {
                                    ?>
                                    <p class="text text-info"><?php echo $pvalue->description; ?></p>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text text-left"><?php echo $pvalue->paying_date; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="text text-left"><?php echo $pvalue->payment_mode; ?></td>
                        <td></td>

                        <td class="text text-right"><?php echo (number_format($pvalue->amount_discount, 2, '.', '')); ?></td>
                        
                        <td class="text text-right"><?php echo (number_format($pvalue->amount_paid, 2, '.', '')); ?></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="text text-right">
                        <div class="btn-group pull-right">

                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default printInv"
                            data-advance_id="<?php echo $pvalue->advance_id; ?>"
                            data-balance_id="<?php echo $pvalue->balance_id; ?>"
                            data-farmer_id="<?php echo $pvalue->farmer_id; ?>"
                            title="Print Invoice">
                            <i class="fa fa-print"></i> </button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>     
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
         <!-- FOOTER -->
        <tr class="box box-solid total-bg">
            <td align="left"></td>
            <td align="left" class="text text-left">Grand Total</td>
            <td class="text text-center">
                <?php
                echo ('<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>' . number_format($total_amount, 2, '.', ''));
                ?>       
            </td>

        <td align="left"></td>
        <td align="left"></td>
        <td align="left"></td>
        <td class="text text-left"></td>
        <td class="text text-left"></td>
        <td class="text text-left"></td>
        <td class="text text-left"></td>
        <td class="text text-right">
        <?php
              echo ('<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>' . number_format($total_discount_amount, 2, '.', ''));
         ?>    
        </td>
        <td class="text text-right">
        <?php
         echo ('<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>' . number_format($total_paid_amount, 2, '.', ''));
         ?>
        </td>
        <td class="text text-right">
        <?php
         echo ('<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>' . number_format($total_balance_amount, 2, '.', ''));
         ?>
         </td>
         <td class="text text-right"></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this works for me to make unpaid rows to remain zero but in Grand total row (tfoot)  total paid amount is more than total amount, please refer image above.

Comment: Updated code,everything working fine, but the total paid amount of each fee type row is appending with all other fee type rows, for example if 1st row having total 9000 balance and i paid 1000,like 2nd row having 5000 total balance i paid 3000 in that, here in 2nd row the paid amount is not showing exactly 3000 it is sum up with 1st row paid amount and displaying 4000 instead, i want it to display 3000 only, if if u r not able to understand my lines, please please refer image which i attached with question, thanks for your support and patience.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine now, i just add the sum of all paid amount group by balance id.

Controller:

```
public function issueAdvance($company_id){
        if($this->session->userdata("is_active") == 1){

          $seedIssue =$this->seed_issue_model->selectFarmer($company_id);
          $singlefarmer =$this->seed_issue_model->selectIssueDates($company_id);
          $crops = $this->seed_issue_model->get_crop_data(); //Crop
          $pc_code = $this->seed_issue_model->get_pc_data(); //Production-Code
          $advance_amount =$this->advance_model->getLoanData($company_id);
          $paid_installments = $this->advance_model->paidInstallments($company_id);
          $total_paid_amount = $this->advance_model->paidAmount($company_id);
        // echo '<pre>'; print_r($total_paid_amount); echo ("</pre>"); exit();
          if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == "GET") {
                $data = array(
                  "page_content" => "advance/view_advance_issue",
                  "singleFarmer" =>$singlefarmer,
                  "issueSeed"  =>$seedIssue,
                  "crop_result" =>$crops,
                  "pc_result" =>$pc_code,
                  "farmer_loan" =>$advance_amount,
                  "paid_installments" =>$paid_installments,
                  "rowpaidAmount" =>$total_paid_amount
                );
                $this->load->view("layout/main_layout",$data);
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
   public function paidAmount($company_id){
        $query = 
            $this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(p1.amount_paid)) as amount_paid,(SELECT SUM(p1.amount_discount)) as amount_discount,p1.balance_id')
                ->from('tbl_pay_amount as p1')
                ->join('tbl_balance as b1', 'p1.balance_id=b1.balance_id') 
                ->group_by('b1.balance_id')
                ->where("p1.farmer_id", $company_id)
                ->get();
                return $query->result();
    }
```

View:

```
<?php
                $total_amount = 0;
                $total_discount_amount = 0;
                $total_balance_amount = 0;
                $total_paid_amount = 0;
                
                foreach ($farmer_loan as $key => $balance) {
                    $discount_amount = 0;
                    $paid_amount = 0;
                    $total_amount = $total_amount + $balance->amount;
                }           
                 foreach ($farmer_loan as $index => $value) {    
                    $balance_amount = $value->balance;
                    $total_balance_amount = $total_balance_amount + $balance_amount;
                    $total_discount_amount = $total_discount_amount + $discount_amount;

                    foreach ($rowpaidAmount as $index => $pvalue) {                        
                        if(($pvalue->balance_id != $value->balance_id))
                            continue;
                         $discount_amount =$pvalue->amount_discount;
                        $paid_amount = $pvalue->amount_paid;
                        $total_paid_amount = $total_paid_amount + $paid_amount;

                    }
           ?>
```